# Schedule .bat isn't executing VBScript properly

Tags: vbscript, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

So I've got 2 things going on: a program that checks the status of some folders, then a VBScript that runs afterwards to email recipients of any errors going on in said folders. Even if there is none, it's supposed to send a "No Errors" email.

Both of them work perfectly fine individually. The checker .exe program runs with no issues, and when I run the VBScript by itself, it sends all the emails it's supposed to. However, I put the following into a .bat file to run nightly at 11pm:

```
"C:\batch\night_monitor\checker.exe"
"C:\batch\night_monitor\emailer.vbs"
```

For some reason, when the batch file is run, only 1 out of 5 emails go out. By default, all the flags are set to true, and when I look in the log file, I see that the emailer.vbs is only checking 2 error logs instead of 5. Like I said though, the emailer works perfectly fine if I just run it by itself. Is there something major that I'm missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this..

```
@ECHO OFF
START "Checker" /WAIT "C:\batch\night_monitor\checker.exe"
START "Emailer" /WAIT "C:\batch\night_monitor\emailer.vbs"
```

Run `START /?` from a command line to see all the options.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your *checker.exe* isn't finished when *emailer.vbs* is started.

Try running your programms in sequence:

```
"C:\batch\night_monitor\checker.exe" & "C:\batch\night_monitor\emailer.vbs"
```

... or execute `emailer.vbs` only if `checker.exe` executed successfuly:

```
"C:\batch\night_monitor\checker.exe" && "C:\batch\night_monitor\emailer.vbs"
```

Another alternative would be to call `checker.exe` from inside `emailer.vbs` to make sure it has finished before you access the error logs.